# Standard way to handle export/import for pure javascript web app?

Tags: javascript, json, import, export

I want to add export and import to an app I'm building.  Not really sure how to go about it.  I guess I need to generate a temporary file on the server, have the user download it, and then delete the file after, say, an hour?  The app is pretty much all client side javascript though, and ideally I'd like it to stay that way -- but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to give the user a downloadable file purely from javascript(?)  I've looked into data: links, but that (in Chrome at least) seems to result in a popup window, and the user would have to manually copy and paste the data into a file on their computer(?)  Kind of lame...  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

With application/octet-stream mime-type browser will save the file. But it seems the file name can not be specified :(

```
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,eyBuYW1lOiAnSm9obicsIGFnZTogMzYgfQ==">save data</a>
```

Comment: Man, that's 90% of what I want -- but I think downloading a file with a weird filename would just confuse users.

Comment: There is a proposal for 'download' attribute http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download but I don't know if any browser implement that yet.

Comment: That's cool.  It looks like I'm going to have to use downloadify or go with a server side solution in the meantime though...